# Remove space before specific substring

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I think regex can help me here.

Lets say I have String `What is foo. Where is foo. How is foo. Why foo? When foo? together foo. lol foo`

How to remove space before each `foo`?

Comment: What should I try? I do not have any Idea about it. I have used replace and other methods. But that is for some other scenario. I think I have to look into pattern matching. But I am not sure.

Comment: Assuming that we are removing spaces before `foo`, what should be result of `"data foo foobar"`? Should it be `"datafoo foobar"` or `"datafoofoobar"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
public String replaceSpaceBefore( String sentence, String word ) {


     return sentence.replaceAll(" " + word, word);


}
```

In your example, the parameter "word" would be "is" and "sentence" would be "what is your name".

Comment: And what if string contains word `isn't`? With your solution OP will also remove space before this word. There is one thing missing here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Comment: Then more workaround is needed, but OP just asked a simple question with a simple example.

Comment: Aadam, it does not change the answer, because `replaceAll` is going to do the job for all the occurrences.

Comment: Oh my. I have tried replaceall but in some other way. That was really simple. Thankyou all

Comment: @Aadam Can your `word` be for instance `U.S.A` or `A*` or `a+b`?

Answer (score 0):

I would give it a try by replacing the whitespace by an empty string or grabbing 'What is' and put it as 'Whatis' into a new string. But I never did Java before so I don't know if it works the same as C#.

Answer (score 0):

What language do you need it for?

You could just replace every occurence of 'What ' with 'What' and the space is gone. You could achieve that with every texteditor that supports simple replacement.

Update:
In Java you would do:

```
str = str.replaceAll("What ", "What");
```

### Update concerning 'foo'

You can easily apply that to anything.

```
String str = "What is foo. Where is foo. How is foo. Why foo? When foo? together foo. lol foo";
str = str.replaceAll(" foo", "foo");
System.out.println(str);
```

Will output

```
What isfoo. Where isfoo. How isfoo. Whyfoo? Whenfoo? togetherfoo. lolfoo
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
"What is your name".replaceAll("(What) (\\w+)", "$1$2")
```

It will take "What" followed by a space, followed by some word (can be anything, for example "is" in your example),
and replace with the two concatenated words, without the space in between.

Answer (score 0):

Use the String library. First find the location (character index) of "your name". Grab the substring from the beginning of the string up to that point (so you'll be left with "What is "). Trim that to remove the trailing space, then call String.replace(" ","") to remove the space between the two words. And then this will work regardless of what "is" is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the method `public String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)`?

Using this you could do something like this:

> Str.replaceFirst("\s", "" );

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to read your question, but my interpretation is to remove a single space between the first and second word.

```
public class Junk {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strings = {
              "What is the name of your cat?",
              "Who are all these people?",
              "How do I code things?",
              "I'm not feeling well.",
              "Don't"
        };

        Junk junk = new Junk();

        for(String s : strings){
            System.out.println(junk.removeSpaceBefore(s));
        }
    }

    public String removeSpaceBefore(String full){
        // Use capturing groups. $1=First group.  $2=Second Group
        return full.replaceFirst("(\\w+)\\s(.+)","$1$2");
    }
}
```

And the output

```
Whatis the name of your cat?
Whoare all these people?
Howdo I code things?
I'mnot feeling well.
Don't
```